# Can differing A, CNAME, TXT, and NS records in multiple domains TLD's cause email deliverability issues?

Tags: top-level-domains, cname, mx

I'm troubleshooting an issue where, after switching TLD's internal and ESP-based emails are getting blocked when going to external customers. Could different A, CNAME, TXT, and NS records cause email deliverability issues?
Short of posting actual differences, is there anything obvious before I look for other issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of-course this is possible, although the problem is less likely to be a CNAME, A or NS record issue (although it is possible)  and more likely to be a TXT record issue or something else.

TXT records are actually generic records which little inherrent meaning.  e-Mail uses these TXT records to provide additional security/validation of the domain - for example SPF records (which are a type of TXT record).  If your TXT record incorrectly describes your mail server and acceptable relays it is very likely that this will stop delivery.

It is, of-course, possible that your issues are not DNS related at all, but related to the lack of reputation of your nameserver and/or domain.

Comment: I would agree about the reputation, but what confused me was that their internal emails to existing clients are getting blocked.

Comment: Do you have an SPF record set up, and if so, have you validated it?  Are the emails going to spam or being g rejected? If the latter, what does your SMTP servers log say?

Comment: Yes. And it’s validated. I wanted to kick the tires before I fell back on the reputation angle

Answer (score 0):

The biggest DNS culprit for email delivery problems in a CNAME record at the domain apex (no subdomain).   It is perfectly legal to have a CNAME for any subdomain, but it is not permitted to have one at the domain apex.   The DNS specs say that you can't have a CNAME and also other record types.  Since the domain apex has to have SOA and NS records, a CNAME there is not allowed.

Despite this, some DNS providers don't prevent you from trying to create a CNAME at the domain APEX.  If you do so, the most obvious thing that breaks is email delivery.   When email systems see the CNAME at the domain apex, they ignore your MX records and try to deliver email to the MX records of the domain specified by the CNAME.

Comment: the CNAMES are pointing to subdomains under the domain, if I'm understanding you correctly. So the issue isn't that two TLD's it could be how they're both set up?

Comment: Its not where the cnamrs are pointing to, its where they are pointing from.  Does "example.com" include a cname "xyz.example2.com" have a cname? That would break spec.